# Xubuntu Install-No Network

Tags: networking, software-installation, ifconfig

I installed **Xubuntu 14.04** clean on a Dell Vostro 1000 and now I have no network at all. 
Entering `ifconfig` gets a return of `ifconfig not found.`

Everything was fine from the live disk.

Answer (score 1):

`ifconfig` is actually `/sbin/ifconfig`. It sounds like the `/sbin` directory is not in your `PATH`. Either add `/sbin` to your `PATH`, or type the command as `/sbin/ifconfig`